# Android app-icon not appearing after installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio, and made a simple app.
When I install the APK file on my phone, it installs fine, but there isn't any app icon appearing on my homescreen.

This question has been asked before, and the answer is that I need the following lines in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

They're already there. Here's my full AndroidManifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pizza.learn.learnpizza">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. Also please don't append _solved_ to the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly change in menifest file.... here

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

replace ic_launcher with

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

and remove this line from Menifest File

```
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: I changed it, but the icon is still not appearing.

Comment: Do u add "ic_launcher_round"  icon in mipmap folder?

Comment: Yes, the icons are there. And also when the app installs, it does show the correct icon during installation. The icon just still doesn't show up on the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, simply copy and paste in your manifest file

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pizza.learn.learnpizza">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```